# status change missing from bitbucket comments

Tags: api, bitbucket, status

Since bitbucket is ending support for mercurial, I am working on a program to automate the move of the projects to sourceforge, which (still) supports mercurial.

Using some sample API 2.0 code to list the repositories on bitbucket, I found that the repo information, loaded from the paginated JSON result, contains links to other information (non-interesting links shortened to `....`):

```
links:
  avatar: ....
  branches: ....
  clone: ....
  commits: ....
  downloads: {href: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user/slug/downloads}
  forks: ....
  hooks: ....
  html: ....
  issues: {href: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user/slug/issues}
  pullrequests: .... 
  self: ....
  source: ....
  tags: ....
  watchers: ....
```

Using the links I can automate getting all of the downloads, and all issues.
The mercurial repository itself, can of course be pulled and pushed quite easily.

Each issue has links as well:

```
links:
  attachments: {href: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user/slug/issues/1/attachments}
  comments: {href: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user/slug/issues/1/comments}
  html: ....
  self: ....
  vote: ....
  watch: ....
```

I have no way to map a bitbucket user to a sourceforge user, but I can add the individual comments to sourceforge including info on their original poster in text form.

When you change the state of an issue, e.g. closing it, you get an additional comment on bitbucket (with optional text). Unfortunately such comments gathered from the API have no information on the state changes and none of the others links found, provide this information.

Do I need to scrape the individual issues on the bitbucket website to get the *changed status* information, that can be seen there?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the JSON that is provided by exporting issues from bitbucket, did see the following top level keys:

```
attachments:
comments:
components: 
issues:
logs:
meta:
milestones: 
versions:
```

and the `logs` section actually contains the status change information. Trying with a url of the form

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user/slug/issues/1/logs
```

but that didn't work.

Although I could automate retrieving the export and logs from the JSON from the zip file exported, I finally stumbled upon [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/issues/%7Bissue_id%7D/changes) information in the documentation. So the URL to use is

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user/slug/issues/1/changes
```

The first changes entry is the creation, so that is less interesting. The rest of the entries overlap with comments. Since the changes include the comment text (if any) you can overwrite the comments with the more complete changes information based on the creation date-time-stamp (which seems equal to the microsecond).